# Correcting a selected range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet where the user selects a non-contigious range of cells (ie E4, F6, G7) which I want to be able to convert into (A4, A6, A7) keeping the row number but changing the column. I want to only return a single value however if they select more than one cell in the same row or worse still select the entire row.  I am a little out of practice with my VBA and can't figure this one out

Comment: Doesn't make sense, select three cells but return a single value?  Do you want to copy/move the contents of those cells into other cells?  Or do you want to concatenate the elected cell values into one value?

Comment: `Dim rng As Range` `Set rng = Range("E4, F6, G7")` `Set rng = Intersect(rng.EntireRow, Range("A:A"))` `Debug.Print rng.Address`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Offset` and `.Resize` do not work with non-continous ranges. But dou can use some tricks to get that done.

The idea is to convert the user's selection into an entire row selection and intersect that with the range of column A. The result is the intersecting cells in column A with the originally selected rows.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SelectAInSelectedRows()
    Dim UserSelection As Range
    Set UserSelection = Selection.EntireRow  ' make user's selection entire row
    
    Dim SelectARange As Range
    Set SelectARange = Intersect(UserSelection.Parent.Columns("A"), UserSelection)  ' intersect the rows with column A
    
    ' select the resulting range in column A
    SelectARange.Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this into a relevant worksheet module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not (Intersect(ActiveSheet.Columns(1), Target) Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub
    ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value2 = Target.Value2
End Sub
```

You can also check if the output cell is not empty, then change